# What is wrong with my if else statements?

Tags: c, if-statement, input, printing, conditional-statements

This code is functioning almost perfectly but it seems to be ignoring my if else statements. The goal of this program is to only convert temperatures between -100 and 100 but for some reason my code is still converting any number that is entered. It is frustrating because I have tried several different approaches but the program never goes to the else statement and always runs the if statement even if say I entered 10000. Thank you any advice would be appreciated

```
double converter()
{
  float C, F, S; 
  int input;
  printf ("Please enter a temperature in Fahrenheit:");

  scanf ("%f", &F); 

  if (F > -100 || F < 100) {

      C = FCR * (F -32);

      printf ("%f F ==> %f C    ", F, C); 
      printf ("%f", F);
  }
  else {
  F = pow(C, 3);
  printf ("Invalid Fahrenheit temperature.");
}
}
```

Comment: `C` is uninitialized in your `else` claus, and what is the point of setting `F = C^3` any way?

Comment: `F > -100 || F < 100` is true if F is 150 because `150 > -100`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently your `if` condition will accept any Farenheit temperature *greater* than `-100` or *less* than `100`.  Well this means that *every* temperarure will enter that `if` statement.  You probably intended to use AND instead:

```
if (F > -100 && F < 100) {
    // logic here
}
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't realize the logic was wrong there

Answer (score 2):

Change || to && and it shall work.
If one side of `||` is true, you enter the if.
And a 1000 is indeed greater than -100

One more note. C is uninitialized. You only assign it a value if the expression in the if evaluates to true. But in `else` you use the C when it is not initialized.  And always check the return value of `scanf`.